# How do I create CloudWatch outage monitoring for AWS direct connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-direct-connect

Please guide me on how to create monitoring for AWS Direct Connect. I tried with CloudWatch. But there is no direct connect metric in this list.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case people are still looking for the answer to this,  the metrics will not be available to you if your connection is hosted via a partner:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html

> If your connection is a hosted connection from an AWS Direct Connect
>   partner, you cannot view CloudWatch metrics for the hosted connection.